# Stopping forever at Await in Async-Await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I am using NodeJS express and MongoDB to create a registration system for my website. In the code below, when testing, my program always stops at the line **let usernameExist = *await*...** No data is currently entered in my database in MongoDB Atlas, so this means that when I call **User.findOne(...)**, it should return **null** if I am correct. However, it stops at this line of code forever in Postman, and eventually returns "Could not get any response," without continuing to the rest of the code. Why is this?

```
router.post('/signup', async(req, res) => {

    let errors = [];

    //validate data

    const {error} = schema.validate(req.body);

    //schema defined above with package @hapi/Joi

    if(error) errors.push(error.details[0].message);

    let usernameExist = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(usernameExist) errors.push("Username already exists");

    //Hash the password

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    if(errors.length == 0 ){

    //adds data in database if no errors are present with json fields

    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: hashPassword,
    });

    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
  }
});
```

---

Adding this code in the beginning before **let errors = []**, now my code again stops at **await** in the try block. This extra code was used to test what would happen if a document was added to the database before checking if a *username exists*.

So now the new problem is: Why does this happen? Can it not add this data to the **User Schema** I define below this code.

```
const u = new User({
        username: "AkshatM",
        password: "2143424204",
    })
    try{
        console.log("hooray");
        const save = await u.save();
        console.log("ok I think I figured it out");
        res.send(save);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("error");
    }
```

---

User schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),

userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6, 
        max: 255,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 1024, 
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

---

I finally figured out the problem. In my MongoDB connection string, I left in the **<(...my pasword)>** in  without removing **<>**. My code was never connecting to the right database. Anyways, thanks everyone...

Comment: You need to move your `try` to the top of your function. As it is now if your first `await` generates an error you will never know

Comment: Trying that, I told it to log the error in the catch loop. However, nothing came to my console, so it is still executing the try block & the same result occured

Comment: Does it work if you have a document in the database? Do you face the same issue if you use mongoDB on local machine?

Comment: Using the package mongoose in my code, it connects to my mongoDB Atlas and it should create a collection or a schema like User. Let me see what happens if I add a preexisting document to the collection